# Какой из запросов оптимальнее?

Tags: mysql, sql

Таблицы `book` и `supply` не связаны друг с другом и в них перечисленны различные книги. Необходимо удалить книги, цены которых содержат "99 копеек".

Подскажите, какой из запросов меньше нагружает БД и почему? Или, может быть есть какой-то значительно более оптимальный вариант (кроме как сделать это в 2 отдельных запроса)?

```
delete book, supply 
from book, supply
where book.price-floor(book.price)=0.99 and supply.price-floor(supply.price)=0.99;
```

или

```
delete book, supply 
from book JOIN supply ON 
book.price-floor(book.price)=0.99 and supply.price-floor(supply.price)=0.99;
```

Я предполагаю, что второй должен быть "легче", т.к. мы избегаем CROSS JOIN'а двух таблиц (который, насколько мне известно, и происходит при использовании синтаксиса FROM t1,t2 ...)

Comment: запросы абсолютно одинаковы. забудьте про то что в теории считается cross. оптимизаторы современных СУБД умные и если в where есть условия соединения то для них запятая не cross join, а обычный join. а еще если количество записей в таблицах сильно разное, то оптимизатор в обоих случаях вполне может это понять и отобрать сначала из нее подходящие записи, а потом перепроверить условие, выполнив join только к таким записям. И в любом случае когда возникают вопросы с производительностью начинать надо с получения реального плана выполнения. см. https://habr.com/ru/post/211022/

Comment: Оптимально будет обрабатывать каждую таблицу отдельно